# ASP.net Nested Repeater Puzzle: Basing inner SQL Query on data from outer repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Okay I'm afraid that title may be confusing, so let me try to describe this with my example. Let's say I have a SQL Server table with 2 columns, a Text column and a Category column.

In my nested repeater in this code, I want to display all the data rows from the SQL Server table which share the same category. **However**, the category itself I need to get at, is coming from the above repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterOuter" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGrantCategories">
<ItemTemplate>

<%# Eval("Category") %> //Here I can access Category just fine.

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrantInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand='<%# "SELECT * FROM [cfhudson_grants] WHERE Category =" + Eval("Category") %>'  /> //Here I cannot access the current Category coming from the outer repeater, so I cannot make a query based on Category :(

    <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterInner" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGrantInfo">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Text") %> //Text from the current data row.
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater> //This repeater should list all rows of the current category.

</div>    
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater> //This repeater brings the next Category to the nested repeater.
```

I'm having trouble getting that category data from the outer repeater, to use inside of a query to another SQL Server table which also has a column in it called `Category`. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this, or if there is a way to do this sorting with the SQL queries.

In simplest terms, I just want to sort my data with these repeaters by `Category`. So have them create something like: Category1, Cat1Data1, Cat1Data2, Category2, Cat2Data1, Cat2Data2, so on and so forth.

I would be happy to provide more info on this problem, as it is preventing the final touches from being made on a nonprofit website I'm working on for kids. This problem has been going on for over a week now. I am pretty new to ASP.net, C#, and SQL Server. Hopefully someone else has encountered a similar thing. It doesn't seem too farfetched, it seems quite common but there is little documentation online about it.

Comment: If ANYONE has done a nested SQL query program, this problem is still ongoing.  I'm likely working on it as you read this.  I will accept and upvote any answer which helps me reach a solution.  Thank you those who have replied.

Comment: Okay so the solution was that my columns in both of my SQL tables were made in text, so I had to wrap my query statement in quotes!!!  Will update with solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `SelectCommand` to this:

```
SelectCommand='<%# getQuery(Eval("Category")) %>'
```

so the `SqlDataSource` looks now like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrantInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CMSConnectionString %>" SelectCommand='<%# getQuery(Eval("Category")) %>' />
```

add the following function in your code behind:

```
public string getQuery(object cat)
{ 
    return "SELECT * FROM [cfhudson_grants] WHERE Category ='" + cat.ToString() + "'";
}
```

that should work.

Comment: Both good answers but I like this one because it avoids too much complexity, but seems like it does what I need.

Comment: Okay I tried this today and it still isn't working properly.  I get an error that a column is not found, even though I am selecting all with * in both of my queries.

Comment: What happens if you run the same query with your sql client? Are you sure the Category field is written like that?

Comment: I can't run a query on the actual tables, but I set up some test tables the exact same way, and the test queries seem to work!  I've looked very very carefully at the way the real tables are set up... I mean I checked about 20 times now to make sure that there indeed are the right columns in each.  Both tables have a Category column, which have the exact same data in them as text.  One table just has the Categories, for the outer repeater to loop over each category once.  Then the other table, has each row having a Category, so the nested repeater can pull all similar rows by Category.

Comment: Ok, what if you instead of calling the function write the query in the  SelectCommand with a Category that you know exists. That way we rule out it is not the code I provided for you, but rather something wrong in the DB or not...

Comment: Actually, I take that back.  I STILL get an invalid Column name error when just directly typing in a query, which only looks at one query.  Sorry about that.  I will continue to try different kinds of queries.

Comment: After much debugging and trial and error, this solution now works.  I hope this finds it's way on to Google so more people can view this solution!

Answer (score 2):

The key is to add an event handler to ItemDataBound that binds data to the nested repeater for each row like this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6140/A-quick-guide-to-using-nested-repeaters-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Is this something going on in the code behind?  I'm confused here, but thank you a lot for the link.  That is one I haven't read yet so maybe it can help.

Comment: Yes. The method I linked to will avoid the need for a SqlDataSource, but will have a line or two more of code in the code-behind.